# How do I clear from the println() command on Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

all! Is there any way to remove text that has been printed to the console? I can write a message easy enough with

`System.out.println("Hello world!");`

but how do I remove it once it's been put up? It is possible to do so? I am using the Eclipse IDE, by the way.

Comment: If you're interested in clearing Eclipse console, then you can look at [Eclipse APIs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fconsole%2Factions%2FClearOutputAction.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible **sometimes**, but mostly not. To do it, you have to be outputting to a terminal that handles ANSI escape sequences, and output the ANSI escape sequence that moves up a line, then output a bunch of spaces. I believe the ANSI sequence for "up one line" is `\033[1A`. Of course, if your output wrapped, one line might not be enough...

You've tagged your question `eclipse`. I'm pretty sure the output panel of Eclipse doesn't support ANSI escape sequences.